# ajax in submitHandle not working

Tags: php, ajax

I used form valiation and ajax to check existing of data, but why after valid, ajax code does not working.
This is my code js:

```
$("#frmSignup").validate({
            rules: {
                ...
            },
            messages: {
                ...               
            },
            submitHandle: function(form) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: fUrl + 'ajax_validExisted',
                    type: 'POST',
                    cache: false,
                    dataType: 'text',
                    data: { email:$('input[name="email"]').val(), phone:$('input[name="phone"]').val() },
                    success: function(data) {
                        if (data == "email") {
                            alert('Email existed')
                        }
                        else if (data == "phone") {
                            alert('Phone existed')
                        }
                        else {
                            form.submit();
                        }
                    },
                    error: function() {
                        console.log('Can not send data');
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Besides, i wonnder why i cleared code line : form.submit(); form still submit ?

my html :

```
<form action="actionURL" method="post" id="frm">
<div style="display:none">
<input type="hidden" name="csrf" value="63b75bbc4e9eff5a96f6725d0a02ffb6" />
</div>
field elements
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: what is the current result ?

Comment: form submit direct to server...it seem not working ajax code.

Comment: give your html form too

Comment: @ safin chacko : i updated html code

Answer (score 0):

```
submitHandler: function (form) {
    $.ajax({
        type: $(form).attr('method'),
        url: $(form).attr('action'),
        data: $(form).serialize(),
        dataType : 'json'
    })
    .done(function (response) {
        if (response.success == 'success') {               
            alert('success');                       
        } else {
            alert('fail');
        }
    });
    return false; // required to block normal submit since you used ajax
}
```

Comment: how about form validation ?

Comment: i think something is wrong here, after ajax run, if true returning, form still submit, otherwise alert.